# Audio file does not appear in play music app

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So I have and android app where i get an audio file from a server and write the file to my sdcard:

```
InputStream inputStream = resp.getEntity().getContent();
File mess = new File("sdcard/Music/message"+ i +".3gp");

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mess);

int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

inputStream.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

However when I do this my file does not appear in the play music app. how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the file path is correct and the file is created? Check it with a file manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Music/message\"+ i +\".3gp\"") ;
```

Comment: I don't know how to get that but it thinks theres a problem with my server side code because I'm sending an 8kb file to the server and saving it there and when i get it back i only get a 1 kb file.

Comment: I guess thats also the reason it wasn't showing because it's not a complete file. When I record and save the file to the sdcard it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your downloaded file hasn't been inserted into the media provider database, and therefor won't show up in the Play Music app.

You could try triggering a rescan of the sdcard after downloading the file:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" +   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```